# Dwarf Fortress Bees Spawning

Tags: dwarf-fortress

The wiki says bees don't spawn in freezing biomes, and my biome freezes during Winter, but thaws during Summer. I haven't seen any bees though. Do they only spawn if your biome NEVER freezes? Or can I just not to expect them during a freezing Winter?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you're forgetting the first step of bees? Bees require *hives*. If there aren't any on the embark, you're out of luck because, currently, they are unable to be imported.

But *Freezing* is maybe a misnomer. It's not, "Biomes which freeze", but rather, a remark on the climate, with *Freezing* being opposite *Scorching*. There are 6 degrees of climate, as follows:

- Scorching
- Hot
- Warm
- Temperate
- Cold
- Freezing

Of the 6, you are likely to have season freezing in Temperate and Cold, while Freezing climates never thaw.

So, in short, check your embark, what was the climate like? And do you have hives?

Comment: "They are found in any area that isn't freezing and can spawn after embark even if not originally present."
http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/v0.34:Honey_bee

The wiki is a bit confusing then. Hives can't spawn over time?

Comment: @Shadow0144 Hm. Maybe they can. I had assumed that hives could not, but perhaps they can? I've never used bees, so I've never paid attention.